# How to use trigonometric substitution to compute this definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have searched for a similar question on stack exchange but could not find one.

The definite integral: $\large\int_0^1 \frac{x^4}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$

I realize that I need to use $x = 5\sinθ$ in the bottom which will get me $5\cosθ$, but after that I am at a loss for what to do.

Comment: For $\int \limits_{0}^{1}\sin^{4}{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$:  http://www.ditutor.com/integrals/integral_sine_4x.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $x = 5\sin{\theta}$, then d$x = 5\cos{\theta} \text{ d}\theta$.  We need to take care of the upper and lower limits (1 and 0), since those are the limits for $x$ and now we are in variable $\theta$.  So, we need to solve for $\theta$ in the equations $0 = 5\sin{\theta}$ and $1 = 5\sin{\theta}$.  For $0 = 5\sin{\theta}$, we can divide both sides by $5$ and take the $\arcsin$ of both sides to get $ \theta = \arcsin{0}$, which gives $\theta = 0$.  Now, for $1 = 5\sin{\theta}$, dividing both sides by $5$ and taking the $\arcsin$ of both sides gives $\theta = \arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}$.  So our new limits are from $0$ to $\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}$.

Thus, making our substitutions, we get:

$\int \limits_{0}^{1} \dfrac{x^{4}}{\sqrt{25 - x^{2}}} \mathrm{d}x$
$ = \int \limits_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}} \dfrac{(5\sin{\theta})^{4}}{\sqrt{25 - (5\sin{\theta})^{2}}} 5\cos{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$

$= \int \limits_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}} \dfrac{(5\sin{\theta})^{4}}{\sqrt{25 - 25\sin^{2}{\theta}}} 5\cos{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$

$=\int \limits_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}} \dfrac{(5\sin{\theta})^{4}}{\sqrt{25(1 - \sin^{2}{\theta})}} 5\cos{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$

$=\int \limits_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}} \dfrac{(5\sin{\theta})^{4}}{\sqrt{25\cos^{2}{\theta}}} 5\cos{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$

$=\int \limits_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}} \dfrac{(5\sin{\theta})^{4}}{5\cos{\theta}} 5\cos{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$

$=\int \limits_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}}(5\sin{\theta})^{4}\mathrm{d}\theta$

$=\int \limits_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}}5^{4}\sin^{4}{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$

$=5^{4}\int \limits_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{5}}}\sin^{4}{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$

---

To find $\int \sin^{4}{\theta} \mathrm{d}\theta$, you need to apply the double angle formulas.  So we have $\sin^{4}{\theta} = (\sin^{2}{\theta})^{2}$.  And, $\sin^{2}{\theta} = \dfrac{1 - \cos{2 \theta}}{2}$, which means $\sin^{4}{\theta} = \dfrac{(1 - \cos{2 \theta})(1 - \cos{2 \theta})}{4} = \dfrac{(1 - 2\cos{2 \theta} + \cos^{2}{2 \theta})}{4}$.

Finally, $\cos^{2}{2 \theta} = \dfrac{\cos{4\theta} + 1}{2}$, so this gives us:

$\sin^{4}{\theta} = \dfrac{(1 - 2\cos{2 \theta} + \cos^{2}{2 \theta})}{4} = \dfrac{(1 - 2\cos{2 \theta} + \dfrac{\cos{4\theta} + 1}{2})}{4}$.

Is it messy?  Yes, but hopefully now it is at the point where you can complete the problem!

Comment: I dont think $\int \limits_{0}^{1}\sin^{4}{\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$ is trivial to perform.  :)

Comment: @Juanito I updated my answer for $\sin^{4}{\theta}$.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The $x^4$ becomes $5^4\sin^4\theta$.

(Also, don't forget there's supposed to be a $dx$, and it needs to become a $d\theta$.)